# Why OpenVPN create keys with '-nodes' option?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, openssl

I was reading about the parameters that OpenVPN build-key script uses to generate a private client's key (with OpenSSL) and I noted the parameter "-nodes".
According to documentation, this parameter is to create an UNencrypted key. 
Well, I'm not OpenVPN expert, so I'm not sure about if I should change this, specially because it's the default option.
Main question is: why OpenVPN make this choice when generating private keys? It's not less secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt the key, you're going to have to provide a passphrase to decrypt it whenever openvpn is started up. Same sort of thing that ssh key-agent does for ssh keys to make it so that you don't have to decrypt them on every invocation, but to my knowledge there is no ssh-agent equivalent for openvpn.

Same situation occurs with x509 key/cert for SSL w/ apache.